# Monodroid hold / Save dependencies between EditTextFields

Tags: c#, android, android-edittext, xamarin.android

I’ve an Interface with many textEdit fields. But any Fields have dependencies to others.

For example:

When textfield_1 is filled, textvield_3 and 4 disabled. But my Layout is Dynamic and I don’t want to Code this dependencies Hard.

Does anyone have an Idea or Solution to Save or hold this dependencies in my Application? And how can I check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your intent correctly I would say the basics would come from ViewModel (as in MVVM design pattern). You could go with the simple INotifyPropertyChanged route or something more "reactive" like RxUI: http://www.reactiveui.net/

All changes happen in the ViewModel (so you can also share it across platforms) and the UI just reacts to changes in the ViewModel data.

Comment: okay thats good and i start to learn how i can use it, it wil fix many problems in my Head ;) but i dont want to code hte dependencies hard an wand to change this dependencies easy. any ideas fpr this ?